# HTML div child nodes aren't aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a basic Wordpress template and looking to have a multi-column front page (showing 2 sets of articles per row). I've done the following in CSS:

```
.front-page-container article:nth-child(odd) {
        width:50%;
        float:left;
        clear:both;
}
.front-page-container  article:nth-child(even) {
        width:50%;
        float:right;
}
```

where `front-page-contaner` is the class of a containing div. The HTML structure is:

```
<div class="front-page-container">
    <article id="post-1"></article>
    <article id="post-2"></article>
    <article id="post-3"></article>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

I want to align post 1 & 2 in the same line, and have post 3 (and 4) on the next row.

While the CSS sort of works, the two posts I want together don't line up as shown is this picture. I've tried adjusting the widths in case there was some sort of overlap but it doesn't fix the issue (even though they get visibly smaller).

[image]

Any help/pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried giving them both `float:left;` rather than left and right?

Comment: @jake That doesn't matter. The problem is that there must be some padding/margins.. maybe even a border, causing the `div` to be greater than 50%

Comment: @JoshC That was my first assumption, until I saw that he said he messed with the widths and it didn't help.

Comment: Given the current HTML/CSS there isn't a problem.. like I said, the width's must be larger than 50% due to margins/padding/or/borders.. http://jsfiddle.net/3gszD/

Comment: Try `box-sizing: border-box` and don't use the `clear:both` on the left floated. Save that for the row or grid container as an `::after` pseudo-element.

Comment: Maybe providing the link would help: [here](http://srv.alexblundell.com/owleyes/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.front-page-container::after { clear: both }

.front-page-container * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.front-page-container article:nth-child(odd) {
        width:50%;
        float:left;
}
.front-page-container  article:nth-child(even) {
        width:50%;
        float:right;
}
```

That should do it. Box sizing makes the divs width the calculation of width minus padding and borders. So no padding or bordering will add to the declared width. (I think thats the best way to explain it). The ::after pseudo-element clears any floats after the container.

As a bonus I will add that this article helped me immensily with this subject:

http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

Comment: There is also a `clear:both` attached to the `.hentry` class that would need to be removed.  But other than that, +1

Comment: @Steve, what `.hentry` class ?

Comment: @CP510 - it's in the OP's code when you look at the link he provided in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks CP510 and @Steve - A combination of both your solutions worked for me :)

Comment: Ahhh yeah. I quickly looked at it. The CSS then for that will need to be changed or even over-written.

Answer (score 1):

You posted code works as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/XqDn6/1/

The issue is most likely some margin/padding on the `article` elements causing the width of each element to exceed 50% and so not being able to fit 2 in a row..

One way to solve this problem is to use `box-sizing: border-box` which means that border/paddings are included in the `width` value.

```
.front-page-container article{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Demo with border/paddings and `box-sizing`: http://jsfiddle.net/XqDn6/2/

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me: http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/6127d1c3a4961de1f9c1ef20d5400d0f.

I have no idea what could be going wrong in your case. Maybe some other CSS is affecting it?

Using the CSS `box-sizing: border-box;` might help, as it makes it so that the maximum width (including padding and border) is the width you defined (in this case 50%);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `clear: both`, as read in [CSS schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp),

> No floating elements allowed on the left or the right side of a specified paragraph.

Here's an exampleo f how clear can be used: [Understanding the CSS Clear Property](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/css-clear.htm).

Though float is an old solution used for stretching the container, as can be seen here: [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Solution: delete that if you can or edit the question for saying why its there (and cannot be taken off) so we can help you further.